# How to know IP address of phishing website?

Tags: networking, security, dns

I am studying cyber security and my homework is to find ways of phishing. I am using xHak9x/SocialPhish tool from GitHub. This tools makes a website for you and give link of it and you have to send it to someone. But website is something similar to this -  "https://07b7523458dbe4.ngrok.io/login.html(the link is not real)". Now I want to know IP address of this website. It is not showing with nslookup or other tools. Is there are any ways of finding this website's IP address?

Comment: Ping 07b7523458dbe4.ngrok.io ?

Comment: @davidgo Ping request could not find host https://07b7523458dbe4.ngrok.io. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: If that is the case, the hostname is not a valid public domain. It exists only on your local system. No surprise, as you would have to purchase the domain or use a dynamic DNS service in real life.

Comment: @Appleoddity but how it can be possible? How someone connect to my local without any domain. And there is additional thing you have to do. Tool gives you a website and you have to register there and then you can open these links.